# WSO2is XACML API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I can use the API REST for XACML without problem following this article https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Using+REST+APIs+via+XACML+to+Manage+Entitlement.

My basic question is, how can i access to pdp endpoint for validate access for the logged user, using the access token of the user that i want to apply the access rules?

For every request i need to send the admin user and password for tenant where the user that i can validate exist. I want to know if is possible to use this same endpoint with the access token that oaut2 token send to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the access token as well

In the Headers of the request, for the Authorization provide the values as below instead of username password.

```
Authorization: Bearer <access-token>
```